# How to add a circle on left/right parentheses?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

I need to use a new symbol to denote an operation defining by myself. How to establish a pair of new delimeters just as adding a little circle on left/right parentheses? The difficulty is there are four size of it: `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, `\Bigg`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\bigl\newlparentheses\sin(x+\pi)\bigr\newrparentheses
\cdot\Bigl\newlparentheses\frac ab\Bigr\newrparentheses\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: @Christian Hupfer I've edited my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define new brackets.

For classic `\left`, `\right` as

```
\def\oright#1{\right#1\mskip-10mu\circ}
\def\oleft#1{\circ\mskip-10mu\left#1}
```

for big `\bigl`, `\bigr` as

```
\def\obigr#1{\bigr#1\mskip-8mu\circ}
\def\obigl#1{\circ\mskip-8mu\bigl#1}
```

and for extra big `\Bigl`, `\Bigr` as

```
\def\oBigr#1{\Bigr#1\mskip-8mu\circ}
\def\oBigl#1{\circ\mskip-8mu\Bigl#1}
```

Use it like:

```
\[\oleft(\sin(x+\pi)\oright)\]
\[\obigl(\sin(x+\pi)\obigr)\]
\[\oBigl(\sin(x+\pi)\oBigr)\]
```

The result will look like:

[image: one bracket]

Comment: That is good. It will better if the size of circle can change compliable with size of parentheses.